# Why is this Ajax taking so long to render?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, setinterval

I have a page that has primarily dynamic content generated by `Ajax`. It is randomized every 30 seconds, and new content from the database appears. The `PHP` seems fine, but there either seems to be something wrong with my `Javascript` code or there is a problem on the database causing it to lag (the Ajax takes about 30 seconds to load!)
It would seem as if the recursive call to `setInterval` in my Javascript is waiting the alloted milliseconds ***before*** executing the function, but I can't find any errors in my Javascript.
Also, there are two image url Strings retrieved from the database, and it seems plausible that Ajax would lag when it has to retrieve information from external sources.
Or maybe is there a lag in my usage of the PHP-`MySQL` syntax `ORDER BY rand()`?
Here is the relevant html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "randomProducts.js" />
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    setIntervalOnload();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the relevant Javascript:

```
    // global static variables
        var subCategory; // initialized from setCategoryTree
        var t; // for setInterval and clearInterval

        var seconds;
        var millisecondsPerSecond;
        var milliseconds;

    function setIntervalOnload()
    {
        getRandomProducts();
        if(typeof t != "undefined")
            clearInterval(t);

        seconds = 30;
        millisecondsPerSecond = 1000;
        milliseconds = seconds * millisecondsPerSecond;

        t = setInterval(getRandomProducts, milliseconds);
    }

    function getRandomProducts()
    {
        //window.alert(subCategory);
        if(typeof subCategory == "undefined")
            subCategory = "all";
        else
        {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = setInterval(getRandomProducts, milliseconds);
        }

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var products = document.getElementById("products");

        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( (req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200) )
            {
                var result = req.responseText;
                products.innerHTML = result;
            }
        };
        req.open("GET", "randomProducts.php?category=" + subCategory, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
    function setCategoryTree(link)
    {
        var categoryTree = document.getElementById("categoryTree");

        /* climbing the DOM-tree to get the category name (innerHTML of highest "a" tag) */
        var category = link.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;

        subCategory = link.innerHTML;

        categoryTree.innerHTML = "==>&nbsp;" + category + "&nbsp;&nbsp;==>&nbsp;" + subCategory;

        getRandomProducts();
    }
```

...and here is the relevant PHP:

```
<?php

    // connect to MySQL
    $dbName = "blah";
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", $dbName, "asdf");
        if (!$db)
        {
             echo "<p>Error - Could not connect to MySQL</p>";
             exit;
        }

    // select the blah database
    $blah = mysql_select_db("blah");
        if(!$blah)
        {
            echo "<p>Error  - Could not select the blah database.</p>";
            exit;
        }

    // fix html characters in $subCategory
    $subCategory = $_GET["category"];
    trim($subCategory);
    $subCategory = stripslashes($subCategory);
    $subCategoryFixed = htmlspecialchars($subCategory);

    // for loop for each random product (total of 10 random products)
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
        // query the blah database for all products
        if($subCategoryFixed == "all")
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY rand();";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        else // query the blah database for products in selected subCategory
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat = " . $subCategoryFixed . " ORDER BY rand();";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
            if (!$result)
            {
                echo "<p>Error - the query could not be executed</p><br />";
                $error = mysql_error();
                echo "<p>" . $error . "</p>";
                exit;
            }

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $productValues = array_values($row);

        $name = htmlspecialchars($productValues[3]);
        $price = htmlspecialchars($productValues[5]);
        $img = htmlspecialchars($productValues[7]);

        // product info is formatted for home.html here
        $str = '<div>
                    <a href = "' . $link . '" title = "' . $name . '">
                        <table id = "product-table" onmouseover = "darkenProduct(this);" onmouseout = "lightenProduct(this);">
                            <tr>
                                <td>' . $name .'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src = "' . $img . '" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>' . $price . '</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </a>
                </div>';
        echo $str;
    } // end of products for loop
?>
```

Comment: `order by rand()` is notoriously slow, do a simple test and order by an arbitrary column and see if your problem's gone.

Comment: You are not running your code inside of onload method.  It is possible that the AJAX setup code runs faster than the page can load so `var products = ...` is null.  Try running in Chrome with console (CTRL+SHIFT+J) and see if any error messages are logged.

Comment: Ok thanks, have run this in Chrome with the console and these error messages are displayed: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`... So it does seem as if `var products` is null. However, I have tried executing the Ajax function itself **first** instead of calling it from another function, and there is no difference...

Comment: No you need to do something like `<body onload='setIntervalOnload();'>` or `window.onload = setIntervalOnload;` to make it run only after the document has fully loaded.

Comment: And @NiftyDude -- I just tried `ORDER BY column_name` (with a specific column name), and that wasn't working either...

Comment: Do you have a live site we can have a look at? Probably faster that way :)

Comment: @mellamokb -- Yes! Now it works, thanks for that! My code was a bit rearranged because I assumed that calling the Ajax in the head section might render it faster, but didn't debug for errors... Chrome is really good for that, I might start debugging with Chrome instead of Firefox. ...and thanks NiftyDude for the help as well.

Comment: @Ian: Glad to help.  I posted my comments as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not running your code inside of onload method. It is possible that the AJAX setup code runs faster than the page can load so `var products = ...` is null.  You need to do something like the following:

```
<body onload='setIntervalOnload();'>
```

or

```
 window.onload = setIntervalOnload;
```

Comment: Now it works, thanks for that! I was incorrectly calling my function `setIntervalOnload()` in the head section, assuming that it might render faster that way, and not taking into account its' dependancy on the page to load **first** (to `getElementById` and not return `null`). Thanks @NiftyDude as well, I am looking into alternatives to `order by rand()` because I am reading that it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` does not call the function immediately. The first run of the function will be delayed by however much the interval is.

You have to specifically call the function yourself if you want it to run immediately as well as on a timer.

Comment: It is run immediately at the top of `setIntervalOnLoad()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have called the `Ajax` function first before `setInterval` and it still does not execute the function first for some reason... Ya, what @mellamokb just said ha.